# Is it possible to write the code to be tested and the testing code in the same source file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

In Visual Studio IDE, I can create a unit test file with a unit test class for the code in a source file, by right clicking inside the code to be tested and selecting the option to create unit test.

The testing code and the code to be tested are not only in the same file, but also not in the same namespace.

Is it possible to write the code to be tested and the testing code in the same source file?

If yes, how? Should I put them in the same or different namespaces?
Can you give some examples?

Thanks.

Comment: you could. but it wouldn't necessarily be a good idea

Answer (score 2):

It is *possible*, but that also means that you *deploy* your tests with your code, as well as any mocks, dummy data, etc.  All of this is unnecessary and may confuse anyone trying to use the library.

However, to answer the question, just use different `namespace` blocks to separate the test classes in a separate namespace.

```
namespace MyCompany.MyLibrary
{
    // classes
}

namespace MyCompany.MyLibrary.Test
{
    // tests, mocks, etc.
}
```

Comment: I actually like to keep the namespaces the same for the sut and the test class while separating the code by project/assembly name.  So you'd have MyCompany.MyLibrary.dll and MyCompany.MyLibrary.Tests.dll.  Then I don't have to include the MyCompany.MyLibrary namespace in the test class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no restrictions where "code under test" is coming from.

While it is somewhat strange you can have just UnitTest project and put code you trying next to your tests. If you want - even in the same files using same or different namespaces of your choice (C# is not Java and there is no connection bewteen file name/location and namespace)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but

If you put them in the same code base as the system under test, then you will be unable to deploy the system without also deploying the tests.  Do you want the tests sitting on your production servers?

Also, the same app.config (or web.config, depending on your solution) will apply to both your tests and the system under test.  That means you can't set up alternate configurations for things like AutoFac, which normally is handy for unit/isolation testing.